# Why does audioread produce Out of Memory Errors?

Tags: matlab

What I'd like to know is how to either use another function in place of `audioread`, or to expand my available memory. Here's the code:

```
[y,f] = audioread('myfile.wav');
```

where the wav file is a 60MB. Is there a way I can parse my file into a bunch of smaller files and concatenate them in Matlab? Or add additional memory?

I know the problem is the file size, but shouldn't it be possible to read a 60MB file?

Comment: Ben, did any of the answers help you? If so, consider upvoting and/or accepting.

Comment: Rafal's pointed me in the right direction, so I gave him credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try function `wavread('name.wav')` instead of `audioread('name.wav')`. But I think 60 MB is really to much size. My wav file has 100 kB, and I got vector of length 60000 (using `wavread()`).

Comment: I had it originally as `wavread`, but it still had the same error.

Comment: Well, try to split your file into many smaller parts. You can use program Audacity for it.

Comment: I used a smaller snippet and it found an error further down in my code regarding ifft2. It was another out-of-memory error, so if there's a way to use more memory in MATLAB, I'm all ears!

Comment: Did you split your file into 60 small parts, 100 kB each?

Comment: No, I just wanted to check if I could get any size of file past that function, so I took 15s out of the 6min (so about 2.5MB). I'll try a smaller size until it works, but I'd much rather find a way to allocate more memory.

Comment: Just tried it with 5s (860kb) and the ifft2 still gets a memory error.
Thank you for all your help Rafal, but it looks like I'll have to make some significant changes to this code.

Comment: Yes. 860 kB should provide rational results. Good luck with that.

Comment: @BenF, I posted another answer that might help. But now from your comments I realize you do not get the error upon reading the wav file, but upon processing it? You should have mentioned that in the first place!

Comment: I got the first error from the read due to the size. Essentially, the problem of my post has been resolved. Thank you for taking the time to review my question!

Comment: @BenF, if one of the answers helped you, consider upvoting or accepting. If you found another solution not mentioned in one of the answers, consider answering your own question for the benefit of later visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have to do with the fact that each sample in the wav file is represented by 8 or 16 bits (1 or 2 bytes), while the standard number format in Matlab is a 64-bit float a.k.a. `double` (8 bytes), so you need 4 to 8 times as much memory as the file occupies on disk. You can instruct `wavread` to not use double-valued output but native output using the syntax

```
y = wavread('myfile.wav', 'native')
```

which makes the memory size the same as the disk storage size. The drawback is that you get "raw" values in an integer datatype (`int8`, `int16`), while `wavread` normally scales the range of values in the file onto [-1, 1].

On the other hand, 480 MB is still nothing on today's computer systems, where main memory of 16 GB is already in the lower range. Therefore it is really strange to get an out-of-memory error while reading the file. Try to close other programs to get more free main memory, or try to clear other variables in  Matlab with `clear` or `clear all`. Use your OS's memory monitor to see how much free memory there is and which processes eat it up. Rebooting the OS or restarting Matlab might also help.

Comment: I'll have to try truncating my arrays to int8s. 

The memory error is due to only 2GB of MATLAB-specific RAM being allocated by MATLAB for Windows7. 

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conclusion I've reached:

*60MB running through the `audioread` function causes the out of memory error. The only way around it is to split the audio file into smaller files (say, 1MB each), then process/read them individually.